What is the manifold topology of a spinning Cosmic String?
Given the following metric which is that of a rotating Cosmic String:
$$g=-c^2 dt^2 + d\rho^2 + (\kappa^2 \rho^2 - a^2) d\phi^2 - 2ac d \phi dt + dz^2.$$
can one determine the manifold topology underlying this metric?
Mathematically one might pose lots of opposition since they fix the topology before assigning a metric to the topological manifold and in case of Lorentzian geometry the topology induced by the Lorentzian distance does not match the initial manifold topology one started with, and so there's no guarantee that the manifold topology can be recovered from the local metric form (when the spacetime is not strongly casual, the manifold topology is strictly finer than the Lorentzian distance induced topology just like in the case of spinning Cosmic String).
But physically I think knowing enough symmetries, the local metric form (and so local Riemann curvature form and so the topology by theorems like Gauss-Bonnet, Chern-Gauss-Bonnet or more general Index theorems and a complete classification of topological surfaces at one's disposal) can narrow down all the consistent non-homeomorphic topologies if not determining it uniquely [in our case] (NOTE: I know by now that these possible topologies can not be finer or coarser in comparison to each other, but I don't know if they can be distinct).
I'd be thankful if anyone sheds light on this problem.

I'm not sure this is the answer you are looking for.
Given a Lorentzian manifold $(M,g)$ suppose that it's time orientable.
Then there exists a never-vanishing  time-like vector field $v$.
The vector field $v$ and $g$ split the tangent space as $TM = \mathbb R v \oplus v^\perp$. Now define the Riemannian metric $\tilde g$ as
$\tilde g = -g|_{\mathbb R v} \oplus g|_{v^\perp}$.
In this way we have contructed a Riemannian metric in an essentially unique way out of $(M,g)$ which induces a distance compatible with the topology of the manifold.
Putting this in another way: instead of considering the usual definition of distance, there is another notion of distance, that you can build up from your Lorentzian-metric, which gives a metric compatible with $M$.

Where does the topology introduced by this distance match that of the manifold topology on the causal hierarchy?

But what sort of physical notion does this distance bring about? In case of interval topology it is connected with the notion of causality in spacetime?

The topology induced by this metric will be the topology of $M$ and will be thus independent of the Lorentzian metric $g$.  You asked if given a Lorentzian metric it was possible to recover the topology of $M$ in a similar fashion to what is done with a Riemannian metric. The answer is yes; you just need to change the definition of length of a path.

And what about the differential structure? Can you recover it too by means of this metric and its induced topology? Does it fix the diff structure? I know that such thing is possible in case of strongly causal spacetimes https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article-abstract/17/2/174/224641/A-new-topology-for-curved-space-time-which?redirectedFrom=fulltext

And yet I have no clear idea about the physical meaning of such topology. Interval topology is physically the very result of time+space(Pseudo-Riemannian/Lorentzian) and causal structure instead of space alone(Riemannian geometry). Although I still admire the mathematical trick. Thanks

How can I be sure that the new locally defined Riemannian metric is compatible with the same globally defined differential structure over which the Lorentzian metric is defined. How can I be sure that topology recovery is not at the cost of changing diff structure.

The metric $\tilde g$ is defined wherever $g$ is defined and smooth where $g$ is smooth.

locally sure, but what about globally?
And I search for both way arounds, if and only if and not only $\tilde{g} \rightarrow g$@Overflowian

Smoothness of a map is a local property. Also the construction is invertible (once you have chosen the vector $v$).

You are saying that $(M, g) $ and $(M, \tilde{g}) $ are diffeomorphic based on local statements. But I don't see how, specially in $4d$ manifolds that I'm afraid of in general.

And please pay attention you have fixed $M$ a priori and then have recovered its topology. But I am saying take $(M_1, g_1)$ and $(M_2,g_2)$ locally isometric, then are $M_1$ and $M_2$ homeomorphic?

To put it more properly and formally, although your answer is of highest value to me, but what I mean is that the Causal Structure doesn't seem to fix the manifold topology in case of non-distinguishing  spacetimes. Previously I thought Non-strongly causal is enough to maintain the indeterminacy of the manifold topology given that causal structure. But now I see that it's necessary to assume non-distinguishability of the causal structure on the causal hierarchy.

I think it is just ordinary Minkowski with a  singular spacetime surface (one direction being timelike)  at which a spatial wedge is cut out and the sides of the wedge glued back together with a time offset.
You can see the time offset by writing the metric as
$$
ds^2 = - (dt+a d\phi)^2 + d\rho^2 + \kappa^2 \rho^2 d\phi^2 +dz^2
$$
so as you circle the string along the curve $dt + a d\phi=0$ until $\phi = 2\pi$ there is zero spacetime interval between $(t, \phi=0)$ and $(t = -2\pi a,  \phi=2\pi)$, so those points are identified.

What do you mean by time offset? And are you sure this is the only topology consistent? I mean the topology that forgets about the time. (of course the manifold has to be time orientale).

And I would be grateful if you introduce any reference where I can find more explanation regarding the manifold topology.

The time offset does not affect the topology, which is Minkowski, so topologicaly ${\mathbb R}^4$.

But wait a second please. I'm very much confused and maybe I'm too stupid. Not only I don't understand what you exactly mean by the "time offset" but also I don't understand how it can be topologically $\mathbb{R}^4$ while it has singularity. Pardon if I am not able enough.

Doesn't it become a solid torus $\times \mathbb{R}$ perhaps due to the singularity?

Possibly, as your particular metric presumably has the condition $\kappa \rho>a$ where $a/\kappa$ is the radius of the cosmic string core. There would usually be an interior metric  that smooths out the singularity in a  complete theory,   The thin string's singularity should not affect the open sets, as they are are not determined by the  Lorentz-signature metric.

Honestly the metric doesn't have such condition. In fact there're different regimes where namely $\kappa^2 \rho^2 \ll a^2$ and $\kappa^2 \rho^2 \gg a^2$. The topology can be quite nontrivial in the vicinity of the string no?

I am beginning to agree with you. The $\rho$ independent time offset does alter what counts as a continuous function, and so does affect the definition of open sets.  I had forgotten that the offset was $\rho$ independent.  I have added some text to my answer about the offset.

Thanks alot. Do you think the topology can be fixed uniquely?

I think it has to be that of ${\mathcal R}^4$ with the string worldsheet removed.

glued back together with a time offset there is no “time offset”. Identifications are implied only by the role of $\phi$ as angular coordinate and the metric plays no role in them.

@A.V.S. Do you agree that $\mathbb{R}^4 - \mathbb{R}^2$ is not necessarily the unique topological manifold consistent with the given Lorentzian metric?

@BastamTajik the only non-uniqueness is whether we include string worldsheet as part of spacetime. Yes, there is a singularity there, but it is relatively mild, so an argument could be made that there is no need to excise this singularity.

Ok, but Isn't there any limitation on how to fill in the blanks? I can imagine a 2d fractal there instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$ or else. Are you 100% sure that all choice are compatible. Can different choices lead to different topological invariants or differential structure invariants? Though might not physically immediately clearly bear on some known observable in Physics. @A.V.S.

@BastamTajik Why would you expect a fractal from a smooth manifold? On the other hand in quantum gravity people do try to use concepts of dimension that can produce non-integers. See e.g. Carlip “Dimension and dimensional reduction in quantum gravity” arXiv:1705.05417.

My personal thumbnail reason would be: https://mathoverflow.net/q/455574/503363 @A.V.S.
